# Get New Relic running in docker container

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, newrelic, docker-container

I'm trying to get New Relic running in a docker container (`FROM php:7.3-apache`) to push up to Cloud Run.

I've followed this documentation

```
https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/php-agent/advanced-installation/docker-other-container-environments-install-php-agent/
```

For "Install agent and daemon in the same container" and added

```
RUN \
  curl -L https://download.newrelic.com/php_agent/release/newrelic-php5-9.17.1.301-linux.tar.gz | tar -C /tmp -zx && \
  export NR_INSTALL_USE_CP_NOT_LN=1 && \
  export NR_INSTALL_SILENT=1 && \
  /tmp/newrelic-php5-*/newrelic-install install && \
  rm -rf /tmp/newrelic-php5-* /tmp/nrinstall* && \
  sed -i \
      -e 's/"REPLACE_WITH_REAL_KEY"/"NRAK-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/' \
      -e 's/newrelic.appname = "PHP Application"/newrelic.appname = "My apps real name"/' \
      -e 's/;newrelic.daemon.app_connect_timeout =.*/newrelic.daemon.app_connect_timeout=15s/' \
      -e 's/;newrelic.daemon.start_timeout =.*/newrelic.daemon.start_timeout=5s/' \
      /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/newrelic.ini
```

To my docker file and switched the 3 variables to real values.

When I do PS inside the container it looks like it's running but nothing is appearing in the New Relic dashboard.

[image]

When I cat out php_agent.log I get

```
2021-06-21 19:06:34.870 +0000 (1 1) info: attempt daemon connection via '@newrelic'
2021-06-21 19:06:34.871 +0000 (1 1) info: New Relic 9.17.1.301 ("xigua" - "6498785b65c7") [daemon='@newrelic'  php='7.3.28' zts=no sapi='apache2handler' apache='2.4.38' mpm=prefork pid=1 ppid=0 uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0 backtrace=yes 
startup=agent os='Linux' rel='4.19.128-microsoft-standard' mach='x86_64' ver='#1 SMP Tue Jun 23 12' node='544d6a6fd26a']
2021-06-21 19:06:34.871 +0000 (1 1) warning: A global default license has not been set or has invalid format. Please add a 'newrelic.license' key in the global php.ini or in the newrelic.ini file, or ensure that a valid license is provided on a per-virtual host or per-directory basis.
```

When I cat out newrelic-daemon.log I get

```
2021/06/21 19:06:34.974122 (17) Info: New Relic daemon version 9.17.1.301-6498785b65c7 [listen="@newrelic" startup=agent pid=17 ppid=1 uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0 runtime="go1.9.7" GOMAXPROCS=24 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64]
2021/06/21 19:06:35.024983 (36) Info: New Relic daemon version 9.17.1.301-6498785b65c7 [listen="@newrelic" startup=agent pid=36 ppid=17 uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0 runtime="go1.9.7" GOMAXPROCS=24 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64]
2021/06/21 19:06:35.071290 (53) Info: New Relic daemon version 9.17.1.301-6498785b65c7 [listen="@newrelic" startup=agent pid=53 ppid=36 uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0 runtime="go1.9.7" GOMAXPROCS=24 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64]
2021/06/21 19:06:35.071516 (53) Info: collector configuration is &{CAFile: CAPath: Proxy:}
2021/06/21 19:06:35.071855 (53) Info: daemon listening on @newrelic
```

`php --ini` gives me

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-imap.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-mysqli.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_mysql.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-zip.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/newrelic.ini
```

When I  `cat /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/newrelic.ini | grep "newrelic.license"` I get my real correct key

```
; Setting: newrelic.license
newrelic.license = "NRAK-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

What am I doing wrong or what step have I missed?

Comment: I had my USER key instead of my license key, epic fail!

Answer (score 3):

Your license key is wrong.

```
A global default license has not been set or has invalid format. Please add a 'newrelic.license' key in the global php.ini or in the newrelic.ini file, or ensure that a valid license is provided on a per-virtual host or per-directory basis.
```

It's appears that you are putting the user API_KEY: NRAK-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, but acctually you have to put your licence key found on Administration > API Keys  > License Keys

Answer (score 0):

You might want to also actually enable the extension:

```
newrelic.enabled=1
```

... that setting does not have a default value of `true`: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/php-agent/configuration/php-agent-configuration/#inivar-enabled